# Instantiating a new PHPCrawl Class throws the error "Call to undefined method stdClass::receivePage()"

Tags: php, oop, phpcrawl

I use a foreach loop to loop through multiple seed urls.  During each loop, I instantiate a crawler using PHPCrawl and the next seed url.

```
foreach($companyUrls as $companyId => $companyUrl) {
    $crawler = new MyCrawler($companyUrl, $companyId);
    $crawler->go();
}
```

It runs fine for the first loop, but throws the following error the second time through before any crawling has been done:

```
"Call to undefined method stdClass::receivePage() in
/data/utilities/PHPCrawl_070/classes/phpcrawler.class.php on line 201"
```

I have not modified the original PHPCrawl V0.70 classes in any way.  I have only extended the PHPCrawler class and added process code to the handlePageData() function as described in the PHPCrawl documentation. If I run this without the foreach loop (instantiating a new class one at a time with new urls), the system works fine.

Please help!!

Comment: Looks like its a known issue and [supposedly fixed in the version youre using](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3325280&group_id=89439&atid=590146). I was going to take a look but it looks like they arent using a SCM hooked up to the SF repository browser.... or maybe not any SCM at all (sigh)

Comment: You are correct... and I was using V0.70. I was lazy and looked at the online documentation for the version because I just installed this last week.  Turns out they just updated it last week too.  Great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known error and [has been fixed in Version 0.71](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3325280&group_id=89439&atid=590146) (I was using version 0.70).

Thanks @prodigitalson for your comment.